# Open a website with a InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

thanks for your time.

I'm trying to get some help for a ridiculous and most simple app you ever seen in your life. This is what i would like.

I would like my to make the blank Ionic theme show a specific webpage. It's only this!

Without show navigation bar, or open on default browser. And put some ads, to monetize it.

I don't wanna tabs, header, menus and nothing more. Just show some site with ads on the app.

How can I do that?
I have been tryed to use iframe on html body, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Use cordovaInAppBrowser plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Inside your controller

```
var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
    };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://ngcordova.com', '_blank', options)
      .then(function(event) {
        // success
      })
      .catch(function(event) {
        // error
      });


    $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();

  }, false);

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event){

  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
    // insert CSS via code / file
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.insertCSS({
      code: 'body {background-color:blue;}'
    });

    // insert Javascript via code / file
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
      file: 'script.js'
    });
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){

  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var iabRef = null;
function iabLoadStart(event) {
    //window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show();
}
function iabLoadStop(event) {
    //window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide();
    iabRef.show();
}
function iabLoadError(event) {
    iabRef.close();
    onDeviceReady();
}
function iabClose(event) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
    iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}
function onDeviceReady() {

    var target = "_self";
    var options = "location=no,zoom=yes,hidden=no,hardwareback=yes,mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=yes,hidden=yes,keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction=yes";
    //fullscreen = yes,,'toolbar=yes', 'toolbarposition=top'
    iabRef = window.open('http://www.google.com/', target, options);


    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
    iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}
```

More information look cordova document. [Cordova Inappbrowser Document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen)

this code you use .js file and add head tags inside ok.